# Dynamic docker-compose runtime environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, containers

I have a local development setup where I tunnel to a remote database instance and expose that via a port on my machine.

My machine is also host to a docker container that I want to connect to this remote database.

To do this I can't forward the port on `localhost` (which will mean something different inside of the Docker container), so I forward it to the address of my local IP.

`ifconfig en0 | awk '$1 == "inet" {print $2}'` outputs 10.0.0.5

```
ssh -N -L 10.0.0.5:9876:database-instance.website.com:9876 instance-to-tunnel-through.website.com
```

et

Now, in my `docker-compose-yml` I can do:

```
version: "3"

my-app
  ports:
    - 5000:5000 # expose app to host on port 5000
  build: ./my-app # point to my-app's Dockerfile
  environment:
    - HOST_IP=10.0.0.5
```

And then inside of the app I can reference the `HOST_IP`.  This works, but it means that I have to change my `docker-compose.yml` every time I switch networks, which is a pain.

Ideally I would like to feed the container the current output of `ifconfig` when it is started.

I have looked at docker `.env` files but that appears to only house static data.
I have looked at `RUN` in the `Dockerfile`

Comment: I feel you should look into service discovery concept, that will basically register your service with a name that you pass in and will remove the association when u close the service.

Comment: @zenwraight is that still applicable just for local development?  On an actual deployed application my hostnames are static.

Comment: yes u can make use of it in local development as well. I am also not a expert in that area, just know that in theory

Comment: you can take a look at nginx server, it provides all this functionality.